# problem understanding the equality of two basic formulae to calculate derivative of $x^2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm a novice math user and my teacher was very busy so could not explain why I got this at the time I presented my dilemma.

Function is $x^2$.

Let $LHS=RHS$,
I assumed that $x$ summations of $x$ is x$^2$
$x+x+x+...+x = x^2$ and differentiated wrt $x$. as $2+2+2$ is $2*3$ or $6 x^2$ is $x$ addn of $x$.

$$LHS= d(x)+ d(x)+ d(x)+ d(x)+ ...+ d(x)$$ [x differentiations of x]

$$LHS= 1dx+ 1dx+ 1dx+ 1dx+ ... + 1dx $$ [x summations of 1]

$$LHS= (1dx)*x$$

$$RHS= d(x^2)$$ [using $d(x^nx)=n*(x^{(nx-1)})dx$]

$$RHS= 2*xdx=2dx*x$$

$$1x*dx=2x*dx$$

$$1x=2x$$

$$1|=2$$

why is $LHS |= RHS...$ please elucidate,

Answer (score 2):

Your first step is not correct. If $x$ is not an integer, you cannot have $x+...x=x^2$. Also, when you differentiate it, you ignored the face that the number of terms on LHS is also a variable, and derivative is with respect to the variable. Your derivative doesn't consider that.

Comment: thank you for the prompt answer...

Comment: my problem most likely is that x addns of x always gave me x^2 so i thought it would work in calculus too... because whenever i needed to square numbers like 1.6 without, i would add numbers like 1.6 +(.6)1.6 or (1.87)^2 as 1.87+ 1.87(.8)+ 1.87(.07) to get the answer and it would give ok answer..

Comment: I see. Doing computation in that way is correct. But not in calculus. Also that is not really what you wrote. In fact, you cannot represent it using fixed number of terms. That is how it causes problem. You have to have fixed number of terms to differentiate it, otherwise you need to consider it as a variable.